# Virtual function and inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

The code segment below works fine:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class HelpInterface {
public:
    void getHelp();
};

class Applicaiton : public HelpInterface {
public:
    void getHelp() {
        cout << "General help";
    }
};

int main(void) {
    Applicaiton applicaiton;
    applicaiton.getHelp();
}
```

Make the getHelp function virtual in HelpInterface class and I will get a linker error:

```
class HelpInterface {
public:
    virtual void getHelp();
};
```

If I make an empty implemenation of getHelp as below things will work again:

```
class HelpInterface {
public:
    virtual void getHelp() {};
};
```

Can someone please help me understand why virtual throws a linker error unless I have an implementation for getHelp in the base class and why a non-virtual function with no implementation works just fine? In this example, the base function never gets called.

Here is a screenshot of VS2013 with the linker error:
[image: Screenshot from VS2013]

Comment: Can't reproduce. http://ideone.com/NrAvM1

Comment: Not sure why but virtual keyword should not cause linker error. This code works and compiled http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e64d407a206d2979

Comment: @songyuanyao 

The code that does not work for me is if I use:

     class HelpInterface {
     public:
          virtual void getHelp();
     };

Comment: @CoffeeandCode has a very insightful answer. This is related to optimization. With no optimization the [problem happens](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ca669cdbc151f03). But if we inline the base function explicitly, [things will work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31e10c3a8a3b5d5b). Same if we use the -O1 option.

I am wondering why this is exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your base class method to be virtual and provide no implementation, you must set it equal to zero like this:

```
class HelpInterface {
public:
    virtual void getHelp() = 0;
};
```

This is known as a pure virtual method.  It has the effect of making your class abstract and forcing all of its derived classes to provide an implementation of the method.  Consequently, take note that you will no longer be able to create an instance of the base class because it is abstract.

Comment: Please include the correct terminology in your answers (abstract and pure virtual)

Answer (score 1):

When a method is in the base class but isn't virtual the linker will not actually reference the implementation of the method if you don't have an explicit call to that method on either a pointer/reference to the base type (On an instance of the derived class) or an instance of the base type.

Virtual functions can be implemented a number of different ways, and are implementation specific. One of the most common is by using a virtual table. (Also known by virtual method table, virtual function table, virtual call table, dispatch table, vtable, or vftable), and I'm pretty sure your compiler (VS2013) uses this method of implementing virtual functions.

A virtual table is a table of function pointers for the virtual member functions. The class instance would contain a pointer to the table that the class belongs to.

When you make a function virtual the linker tries to put it into the virtual table for that type. It doesn't matter whether you call it or not or instantiate a base class (also an implementation specific detail).

As qexyn has already answered, to get around that you declare the method as pure virtual by adding `= 0` after the virtual function declaration. This tells the linker to put a null pointer in the virtual function table for the class. You can also declare the virtual function pure virtual and also provide an implementation. This forces the derived classes to implement that function, but allows them to choose to use the default method.

Comment: "virtual table" is implementation specific and nothing in the standard says that `virtual` functions have to be implemented like that.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode, yes, and I didn't mean to imply that it was. I've added some clarifications and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that your base class definition is using indirection to get the actual function for `Application`.

This is often implemented with a function pointer, but in any case there could be a derived class that doesn't override the base class implementation.

Although [this isn't usually reproducible](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87fb9acd276c3811) that is simply because member functions are implicitly declared `inline` and when the implementation is visible an optimizing compiler will do exactly that; inline the function. [The proof is in the optimization.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e04971673a9a288)

What you want, is to make sure that every derived class from your base implements `getHelp()`. This is a common idiom and is a core language feature. You want a "pure virtual function". This will make your base class an "abstract base class" which is actually a synonym for "interface" in object-oriented jibber-jabber.

The way to do this in C++ is with a special member-function specific syntax after all of the member function qualifiers (I'm using trailing return types here cause I think they're pretty):

```
class base{
    public:
        virtual auto func() -> void = 0;
};
```

This specifies that `base` is an abstract base class with a pure virtual function `func()` that all classes derived from it will implement.

In your case you would write:

```
class HelperInterface{
    public:
        virtual void getHelp() = 0; // probably want const qualifier
};
```

And just leave `Application` as it is.

You learn something every day, huh?

Comment: You are right that this has something to do with optimization. -O1 will have no problem while -O0 will cause the linker error. What I am curious about is the reason. With the -O0, if I make the getHelp function inline explicitly, things seem to work.  

inline virtual void getHelp();

So, I am curious why when the function is not inlined, the linker error happens.

Comment: @MrAliB because even with explicit `inline`, if you compile without optimization it is possible it won't be inlined. GCC's inlining is kinda like macro replacing, so that's why the optimized version works.